# getting error in ionic capacitor ios platform: RecaptchaVerifier is only supported in a browser HTTP/HTTPS environment

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, capacitor, ionic5

I'm developing `ionic capacitor` app with firebase phone authentication functionality. I have follow firebase documentation and set code to authentication phone with sending otp and verification using firebase.
It's working fine in browser and android device. I'm getting otp and i can verify it also but now i'm creating ios build and find that i'm getting some error

```
code: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment"

message: "RecaptchaVerifier is only supported in a browser HTTP/HTTPS environment."
```

Please find my code below

```
recaptchaVerifier: firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier;    
ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
        size: 'invisible',
        callback: (response) => {
    
       },
       'expired-callback': () => {
       }
     });
}

signInWithPhoneNumber() {
 this.authService.signInWithPhoneNumber(this.recaptchaVerifier, +19898989898).then(
   success => {
     this.verifyPhone();
   }).catch(error => this.afterLoginError(error));
}
```

So the issue is only with ios

Answer (score 0):

On Android and iOS, you should use the Firebase Android SDK and Firebase Apple SDK.
For Capacitor, there is already a [Capacitor Firebase Authentication](https://capawesome.io/plugins/firebase/authentication/) plugin that implements these SDKs and supports phone authentication.

Here is an example:

```
import { FirebaseAuthentication } from '@capacitor-firebase/authentication';

const signInWithPhoneNumber = async () => {
  return new Promise(async resolve => {
    // Attach `phoneCodeSent` listener to be notified as soon as the SMS is sent
    await FirebaseAuthentication.addListener('phoneCodeSent', async event => {
      // Ask the user for the SMS code
      const verificationCode = window.prompt(
        'Please enter the verification code that was sent to your mobile device.',
      );
      // Confirm the verification code
      const result = await FirebaseAuthentication.confirmVerificationCode({
        verificationId: event.verificationId,
        verificationCode,
      });
      resolve(result.user);
    });
    // Attach `phoneVerificationCompleted` listener to be notified if phone verification could be finished automatically
    await FirebaseAuthentication.addListener(
      'phoneVerificationCompleted',
      async event => {
        resolve(event.result.user);
      },
    );
    // Start sign in with phone number and send the SMS
    await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithPhoneNumber({
      phoneNumber: '123456789',
    });
  });
};
```

If you also want to log the user into the Firebase JS SDK afterwards, then additionally check out this guide: https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/blob/main/packages/authentication/docs/firebase-js-sdk.md